# How to check multiple data in dynamic checkbox in mvc using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting multiple value with (,)(comma) sign. Now, I am spliting that (,) sign and check that value in dynamic checkbox.

Now, for a single value it works fine but for multiple value its not working.

for ex : if the value is single value i.e. 6042 then 6042 value will be check in the checkbox. But if the value contain multiple value i.e. 6042, 9099 then it doesnt check in the checkbox.

Here is my code,

//Created Dynamically CheckBox.

```
<label for="VehicleNumber" class="required">Vehicle Number</label><br />
 @foreach (var item in Model.AvailableVehicleNumber)
 { 
     <label>
            <input name="SelectedVehicleNumber" id="SelectedVehicleNumber" type="checkbox" value="@item.Value" />
            <b>@item.Text</b>
     </label>
 }
```

Splitting the Data and Check the value in the CheckBox.

```
var splitVehicleNumber = data.data.VehicalNumber.split(", "),
  $inputs = $('input[name="SelectedVehicleNumber"]');
for (var j = 0; j < splitVehicleNumber.length; j++) {
  $inputs.filter('[value="' + splitVehicleNumber[j] + '"]').attr("checked", "checked");
}
```

Comment: You are creating elements in a loop, all of which have the same id.  That's invalid markup by web standards.

Comment: Also can you show us an example of the generated markup, rather than your templating?  It is much easier for us to provide a working solution, or point out your error(s), if you give us a real example of what the javascript is operating upon.

Comment: but I am getting data by name only not by ID. You can see here $inputs = $('input[name="SelectedVehicleNumber"]');

Comment: That does not change the fact that you are creating invalid markup.  https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-id

Comment: If you dont mine then can you give hint through a code?

Comment: The id note is an aside.  I've already asked for actual markup, rather than the templating, before debugging your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

This will provide you with an array SelectedVehicleNumber with all the checked values.